# Unable to echo user queries in results

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and in the process of making a search engine. The following code will not echo the users input, in the search field, on the results page.

The search page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Search Engine</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background:#F0FFFF;
        margin:-80px;
      }

      form {
        margin:25%;
      } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="result.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="user_query" size="80" placeholder="Enter Search Here" />
      <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search Now" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The results page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Results</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .results {
        margin:5%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#F0FFFF">
    <form action="result.php" method="get">
      <span><b>Enter Query Here:</b></span>
      <input type="text" name="user_keyword" size="80" />
      <input type="submit" name="result" value="Search Now" />
    </form>

    <?php
      if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
          $get_value = $_GET['user_query'];

          echo "<div class='results'>
              $get_value;
              </div>";
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me why the user's input is not being echoed when the search is run?

Comment: Because you're using POST in your form: `method="post"` and try to get the information with GET: `$_GET['search']`? So please use `$_POST['search']` instead.

Comment: because you are sending your form via post and trying to fetch get vars. change $_GET to $_POST and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using method=post
In form tag you must receive you data as $_POST
Also method=get use $_GET

Edit this lines in result page to this

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $get_value = $_POST['user_query'];

    echo "<div class='results'>{$get_value}</div>";

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

well the problem lies in your form tag you should have used method="get" if you want to get some data from database and if you are using method="post" you should have to use $_POST['search'] so your form tag shuld have to be like this

```
<form action="result.php" method="get">
```

and if you are going to use method="post" anyway than your $_GET['search'] should have to be $_POST['search']
but i will suggest you to use method="get" for searching query from database